# Can 802.11n connect 802.11ac router as always?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

My question is straight forward. My laptop uses 802.11n adapter. Now, I'm willing to buy 802.11ac router as it has better performance and speed compared to 802.11n. Will my laptop have full performance of 802.11ac?
The routers I'm willing to buy are [TP-LINK AC1750](http://www.tp-link.com/us/products/details/cat-5506_Archer-C7.html)! and [LINKSYS AC1900 WRT-1900ACS](http://www.linksys.com/us/p/P-WRT1900ACS/)!.
I use Broadcom 802.11n adapter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your 802.11n device will be able to connect to the 802.11ac AP, but only at 802.11n speeds. Wireless routers almost always default to a mode where they let each client connect at whatever speed that client is capable of. So your AC clients will connect at AC speeds, and your N clients will connect at N speeds, etc.

Both the client and the router have to support 802.11ac in order for that client to get the new 802.11ac speeds. Upgrading one end (router or client) to 802.11ac doesn't magically make the other end capable of 802.11ac. 802.11ac is faster because of changes that 802.11n hardware can't handle (80MHz-wide channels, 256-QAM modulation, etc.), so you really have to buy 802.11ac hardware for both the router and client if you want that client to do 802.11ac.

Comment: So, do I have to change to 802.11n mode on 802.11ac router in order to use the network properly?

Comment: @AungMyat All 802.11ac routers I've ever seen default to a mode where they are backward compatible with 802.11n and earlier devices as well, so you shouldn't have to change anything on your router. I'll update my answer to make this more clear.

Comment: You made me clear as crystal. Thanks for your responses.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR** 
As long as the WiFi Standard matches, and the frequency matches - it will connect at the "WiFi Standard" speed (not at the fastest speed possible of the router)

Basically most of the WiFi Router will support several WiFi Standards (a/b/g/n/ac) and also different frequency (2.4GHz, and 5GHz) - at the time of this writing.

So if you check on the Router Specs page for those information (usually in the format of 802.11a/b/g/n/ac or whatever they claim they support) and also whether it is on 2.4GHz or 5GHz -  that should tell you whether your device can connect to those router or not.

If you have older devices, assume it will use the 2.4GHz. The 5GHz frequency devices only came out since end of 2013 - so you may / may not have it.

Caveat1: You will only able to use the speed of the wifi standard - not the maximum speed advertised of the router. So if your device only supports 802.11n, you will be able to connect to the router - but at the 802.11n speed.

Caveat2: 802.11n can use either the 2.4 GHz or the 5 GHz band; 802.11ac uses only the 5 GHz band. Reference: [802.11 Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11)

> Now to drill down to your specific question:

Your laptop having 802.11n will be able to connect to either router (both supports 802.11n at either 2.4GHz or 5GHz - so regardless of your laptop frequency usage, it supports the standards at both frequency).